# CardAction show the title when selected

Tags: c#, asp.net, botframework, messenger

I have a HeroCard with a list of cardActions attach to it.
The cardActions are "PostBack" type but when I click on them, the title of the cardAction selected is sent by the user.

Here's how I create my cardAction :

```
CardAction cardDispo = new CardAction()
        {
            Value = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(date),
            Type = ActionTypes.PostBack,
            Title = $"{Disponibilite.FormatHour(date.Date)}"
        };
```

And here's how it appears on messenger:

[image]

I don't know why it shows to the user even if it's PostBack and not ImBack

Comment: from the documentation on PostBack - `Sends a message to the bot for processing in a way that's hidden from all members of the conversation. *For some channels this may get mapped to a imBack.*`

Comment: *For some channels this may get mapped to a imBack.* Seems like on Facebook Messenger it works like that.
Thanks for the answer